# Backup NAS to an external drive on a connected computer

Tags: backup, external-hdd, nas, synology

I found some options to backup the Synology NAS to an external drive, that is directly connected to the NAS. But is it possible to backup to a computer's external harddisk?

For example, userX starts up his PC and windows connects automatically his network drive to the NAS, it uses the credentials of userX to connect to the NAS.

The NAS knows that userX is connected and could start a backup of the files, to the users external drive. In windows I can also set a fixed drive letter, so maybe the NAS can check if the drive is connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things work on different direction. When you map NAS drive to computer, NAS have no access to this computer hardware. So NAS can't backup to computer disk. You can do it with software which run on the computer.

Comment: Not strictly true. It's a Windows client so the `C$` share (and indeed all the drive letters) is accessible to devices in the same subnet subject to suitable authentication.

Comment: @roaima, AFAIK `C$` give you access to system disk and OP talk about external one, attached to the machine

Comment: @roaima, but maybe you will need admin type account

Comment: Indeed. Or the OP could create a share for the external drive on the Windows client with custom credentials. Too many unknowns and too many assumptions for a straightforward answer.  And then there's the problem of handling an unexpected disconnection of the external drive or even the laptop itself. I'd consider answering specific parts of this question but the requirement as it stands is, I believe, simply a "write it for me" question

Comment: This makes totally sense. I didn't consider the unexpected disconnection at all. So it seems that my idea isn't practical at all and I would consider the software solution. Can you recommend any specific one? It should be for windows and should be able to use rsync. Maybe the software could run in the background and watch if a specific external drive is mounted and then start the backup.

Comment: @catty03, I do not have in mind any reliable solution. IMHO will be wise to delegate this task to NAS.